# Disable multipart upload on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

The goal is to disable the multipart upload on Amazon EMR.

The [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-upload-s3.html) says enter `classification=core-site,properties=[fs.s3.multipart.uploads.enabled=false]` in **Edit Software Settings** when creating the EMR cluster.

My questions are:

1. Can we **modify** the configurations for **existing** EMR cluster? If so, how to do it?
2. Can we achieve the same goal by putting `sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.multipart.uploads.enabled","false")` in the jar to be executed on EMR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot currently modify configurations on a running EMR cluster, but if it's possible for you to start a new one, you could use the AWS EMR Console to clone your current cluster's configuration then modify the configuration before launching it. (Note: Only the configuration is cloned, not any of the data that may be stored in HDFS or on the cluster instances' local disks.)

However, I believe that what you asked about in your second question will work as intended. Have you tried this and found it not to work?